# Drawing an arc attached to a circle with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw an arc attached to a circle?

I tried two methods but failed:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black, fill=none, thick] circle (0.5) ++(45:0.5) coordinate (A) ++(-45:0.5) coordinate (B);
%It accepts the definition of (A), but not of (B).
\draw[thick] (A) to[out=45, in=135, looseness=4] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
(0,0) node(A) [circle,draw,fill, radius=0.5] {} 
\draw[thick] (A) to[out=45, in=-45, looseness=4] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The 2nd method doesn't draw anything. (I know I can use trigonometry to compute the coordinates of the ends of the arc, but I hope for a compact, elegant solution.)

EDIT: I need the arc ends to be orthogonal to the circle. d8xa provided a good solution for the coordinates ++(45:0.5) and ++(-45:0.5). However, it doesn't work for coordinates farther apart, like ++(0:0.5) and ++(180:0.5). (AboAmmar's solution has also a problem with that.)

So I am still hoping not only for the control of the endpoints and their angles but also for some control over the midpoint of the arc.

I can do

```
\draw (A.0) .. controls ++(0:1) and ++(180:1) .. (A.180);
```

or

```
\draw (A.0) .. controls (0,1) .. (A.180);
```

but can they be combined together?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest possible method? See below. There are many other options if you have some specific requirements, but you provided nothing.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick] (0.5,0) circle (0.55);
\draw [fill=white, thick] circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key to the 2nd code block is anchors. You can specify an anchor point of an object like `A` with keywords like `north`, `west`etc, or with angles. Then `A.15` refers to the point at angle 15 on A's bounding box.
This allows you to write the arc like so:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [thick, circle, draw, fill=none, radius=0.5] (A) at (0,0) {}; 
\draw [thick] (A.45) to[out=45, in=-45, looseness=4] (A.135);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But as you can see, it's difficult to get a circular arc like in your drawing with this method. Refer to @AboAmmar's answer for that.

Comment: Thanks, that is great. I am not too particular about the precise shape of the arc, but how can I make it larger (longer)?

Comment: On a related note, I have a problem \draw [thick] (A.0) to[out=0, in=180, looseness=4] (A.180);   I hoped for a nice arc going around the circle, and I get an interval crossing in the middle.

Comment: There is another, more succinct way of writing the arc, by using `arc`: `\draw[-, line cap=round] (A.45) arc (115:-115:0.15);` This solves both problems, but you'll have to do some math or experiment around to find the right angles.

Comment: Oh, and to make the arc in my solution longer, you just have to increase the `looseness`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to figure out what the start and end angles of the arc are. In the following code you can set `alpha` as you wish.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={r=1;alpha=30;}]
 \draw[thick] circle[radius=r]
  (alpha:r) arc[start angle=180-alpha,end angle=-180+alpha,radius=r];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]